# INSERT INTO UPDATE with multiple unique column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with `(id, stock_code, batch_code, qty)`.

`id` is primary key and auto increment value.

`stock_code` and `batch_code` is combine unique. Now I want update in insert query when `stock_code` and `batch_code` is duplicate

example

```
id     stock_code     batch_code      qty
1      r001           b001            100
2      roo1           b002            100    //it should be insert
3      roo1           boo1            120    //it should be update in first row
4      roo2           boo1            130    //it should be insert
5      roo1           boo2            289    //it should be update in second row
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stockcode = "some value";
$batchcode="some value";
$qty = some value;
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$query22 = "select * from table where stock_code= '".$stockcode."' and batch_code='".$batchcode."'";

$result22 = mysqli_query($con,$query22) or die (mysqli_error());

$num22 = mysqli_num_rows($con,$result22);

if($num22 > 0) {
$query222 = "update table set qty='".$qty."' where stock_code= '".$stockcode."' and batch_code='".$batchcode."'";

$result222 = mysqli_query($con,$query222) or die (mysqli_error($con));  
 }
else {
$query222 = "insert into table(stock_code, batch_code, qty) values('".$stockcode."','".$batchcode."','".$qty."') ";

$result222 = mysqli_query($con,$query222) or die (mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: @NullPoiиteя it is deprecated only from 5.5, but in php<5.4 you can use mysql_* functions.But i accept that it is good to practise use of myqsli_* functions where it is supported.

Comment: there isnt php<5.5 tag and since we already know its deprecated then why use it .. downvote was temporary ...and hey i told you reason of downvote instead just downvote and move on ..even i know i can  get  revenge   downvotes :)

Comment: I am not commenting against you,my main reason of comment was to inform you, when you was telling others to use mysqli_* functions which is recommended please dont forget to mention from which version it was availabe, since every one was not aware of it. Anyway thankyou for making me to use better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try use

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

You can read the reff here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATEhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: -1 your answer doesnt seems like an answer since you are asking question ...and its possible comment

Comment: it was a rethorical question... anyway I'm editing it